# Codeception in Jenkins PHP job

Tags: php, jenkins, codeception

Created the following Dockerfile on top of the [Jenkins](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/) image:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM jenkins
MAINTAINER lh <lh@example.com>

USER root

#install required modules
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y \
    phpunit \
    php5-curl

#install composer & codeception & magellanes
RUN curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer \
    && curl -LsS http://codeception.com/codecept.phar -o /usr/local/bin/codecept \
    && chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/codecept \
    && wget http://download.magephp.com/magallanes.latest.tar.gz -O magallanes.tar.gz \
    && tar xfz magallanes.tar.gz \
    && cd magallanes \
    && bin/mage install --installDir=/opt/magallanes

#set date.timezone
RUN sed -i "s/;date.timezone =.*/date.timezone = UTC/" /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

USER jenkins
```

Everything works well and I can build my PHP project. However, my acceptance test fails because I do not know what url I have to configure.

**Codeception configuration**

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://localhost/myapp
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

What should the `url` be? Jenkins places the project inside `/var/jenkins_home/workspace`.

**Jenkins pipeline script**

```
node {
    stage('Preparation') {
        git 'git@bitbucket.org:foo/bar.git'
    }
    stage('Build') {
        sh 'mkdir -p app/cache app/logs web/media/cache web/uploads'
        sh 'composer install'
    }
    stage('Test') {
        sh 'codecept run'
    }
}
```

Comment: You need an http daemon.

Comment: @Naktibalda Basically I need to install Nginx or something in my Docker container. How do I configure that the checkout is automatically configured for Nginx?

Comment: For tests PHP built-in webserver should be good enough: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: Very much appreciated! I was not even aware about PHP her own webserver.